# What is the Drupal 8 Webform url for autofill CiviMail linkage

Tags: webform-civicrm, drupal-8

In D7 Webform Civicrm integration, under Additional Options for Civi configuration there is this link

To have this form auto-filled for anonymous users, enable the "Existing Contact" field for Contact 1 and send the following link from CiviMail:
[https://site.nubay.net/sample-webform?cid1={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}](https://site.nubay.net/sample-webform?cid1=%7Bcontact.contact_id%7D&%7Bcontact.checksum%7D)

I do not see the equivalent link for D8 Webforms.   Would it be the same link?   Should it be in the additional options section?

Answer (score 2):

It works just the same!

Example:

/form/special-resolution?cid1=123&cs=6b8783497eb95b80a04d943f04fa8c5b_1585859799_168

Comment: or in other words, yes appending the tokens to the webform url and sending that link from civi will provide a login for cid=1, ie add ?cid1={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum} (assuming it is contact 1 you are trying to prefill)